# Expected valuable after setTimeout in which is set

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I cannot set for expected valuable to equal in setTimeout.
I have two valuable is:
const first = 0;
const second = 0;

but that throw error is Uncauth TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provider an Observable, Promise, Array, or Interable.

```
setNumber() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     first = 12;
     second = 1235
}, 250);

it('Should execute setNumber', fakeAsync(() => {`
   setTimeout(() => {
     expected(first).toEqual(12);
     expected(second ).toEqual(1235);
   }, 251)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In fakeAsync function use tick() for emulate timeout. Something just like this:

```
it('Should execute setNumber', fakeAsync(() => {
    let first;
    let second;

    setTimeout(() => {
      first = 12;
      second = 1235;
    }, 250);

    tick(251);

    expect(first).toEqual(12);
    expect(second).toEqual(1235);
  }));
```

For understanding, tick with 249 and test will be failed.

```
it('Should execute setNumber', fakeAsync(() => {
    let first;
    let second;

    setTimeout(() => {
      first = 12;
      second = 1235;
    }, 250);

    tick(249);

    expect(first).toEqual(12);
    expect(second).toEqual(1235);
  }));
```

Hope I helped you :)

Comment: When i do follow your suggestion. 
But it's false.
As my understanding is when tick with 250 it's not set yet. but in tick with 251, test can be true.
But i don't know how to set expected after timeout run event clear timeout and set it again

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. Could you write an example?

Comment: i'm so sorry about my reply late.
My example is:
in 250, the first will be set equal 12 and in 251, i expect first equal 12.
But i don't know to test it.